# node_redis CONFIG SET command

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am currently writing an app using redis and I'm having issues with the node_redis library.  In particular I am unable to figure out how to use the redis command from within node_redis

I have tried all the following...

```
client.send_command("CONFIG SET", ["notify-keyspace-events", "Ex"]);
client.config("SET", ["notify-keyspace-events", "Ex"]);
```

This and other similar variants don't seem to be working... Also I cannot find the command detailed out on the node_redis documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ON A SIDE NOTE:  I am using this command to create a client (node-side) that will subscribe to key-expire events (I want to perform a couple clean-up operations every time a key expires).  Is it acceptable to use the node_redis CONFIG SET equivalent or is it better/common practice to start redis-server with a custom conf file?  I would assume the latter however I want to deploy this on Heroku, does that change the circumstances?

Thanks!

Comment: please check this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168559/5229605

Answer (score 10):

You’re very close! The usage is:

```
client.config("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "Ex");
```

Comment: update notify-keyspace-events Ex into redis.conf file and restart server.