# Redis Config Set with Node jS

Tags: node.js, redis

Team,

i am trying to set config of redis at runtime using NODE js application as below.

**let setConfig = await this.cacheConnection.config("set", "notify-keyspace-events", "Ex");
let setConfig = await this.cacheConnection.config("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "Ex");**

Above code is always returning false to me.

I am using redis node module in my application.All other commands like getAsync,SetAsync are working perfectly fine for me.
 let result = await this.cacheConnection.getAsync("keyname");

Any suggestion here would be great.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27554543/3397563 isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node\_redis CONFIG SET command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210840/node-redis-config-set-command)

Answer (score 0):

please set Config after redis client ready to serve commands

```
const redisClient = this.cacheConnection;
redisClient.on("ready", function(err) {
    if(!err) redisClient.config("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "Ex");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i got it working by below code. 
 this.cacheConnection.configAsync("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "KExe$");

Answer (score 0):

this.cacheConnection.configAsync("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "KExe$");