# Facing redis problem: unknown command `config`, with args beginning with: `set` on amazon linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to get around this problem since yesterday but no matter what I do, I just cannot make redis to execute for my project. Here are the details in steps:

Step 1: I created new setup for redis using Elasticache in aws console, then I copied the url mentioned in primary endpoint e.g. my-redisxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com. Thereafter, I assigned custom parameter group to this cluster from aws console where I have also configured the "notify-keyspace-events" in following way:

[image]

It still breaks even if I select default parameter group and don't assign this key.

Step 2: I made ssh connection to my nodejs EC2 instance and went to the environment variables file and assigned this url in this way:

```
REDIS_URI="my-redisxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com"
REDIS_HOST="my-redisxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com"
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_INDEX=14
```

Now all other configurations are working fine in this manner, even redis works if I replace above url with one another existing cluster url. Only this particular new cluster that I made using elasticache seems to be having some problem.

As soon as I run node project using pm2, it hits the wall and throws this:

```
 subscribed to channel ===> __keyevent@14__:expired
0|npm  | events.js:377
0|npm  |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
0|npm  |       ^
0|npm  | ReplyError: ERR unknown command `config`, with args beginning with: `set`, `notify-keyspace-events`, `AKE`,
0|npm  |     at parseError (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)
0|npm  |     at parseType (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
0|npm  | Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
0|npm  |     at Object.callbackOrEmit [as callback_or_emit] (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:91:14)
0|npm  |     at RedisClient.return_error (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis/index.js:706:11)
0|npm  |     at JavascriptRedisParser.returnError (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:18)
0|npm  |     at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:572:12)
0|npm  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/project-directory/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
0|npm  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
0|npm  |     at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
0|npm  |     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
0|npm  |     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
0|npm  |     at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
0|npm  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
0|npm  |   command: 'CONFIG',
0|npm  |   args: [ 'set', 'notify-keyspace-events', 'AKE' ],
0|npm  |   code: 'ERR'
0|npm  | }
0|npm  | npm
0|npm  |  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
0|npm  | npm
0|npm  |  ERR! errno 1
0|npm  | npm ERR!
```

I spent countless hours to understand this problem by reading documentation, only to find out that config command is [restricted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html) in aws elasticache. Also I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166382/redis-config-set-with-node-js) however not able to adapt it in my current code as I am creating redis connection like this (also I am not sure whether this is good solution):

```
const sub = redis.createClient(options);

export const subscribe = async (channel: string) => {
    try {
        sub.subscribe(channel);
        console.log(`subscribed to channel ===> ${channel}`);
        return {};
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("Error while subscribing to a channel", error);
        return {}
    }
}
```

I am completely lost now as not able to think over what can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having similar problem, I was able to solve this by commenting out this line: `this.client.config('set', 'notify-keyspace-events', 'AKE');` from `connectRedisDB()` function located inside `redis.database.ts`. I have commented this line because this parameter is already set in parameter group for redis from aws console, as state above in image.